# get json for dynamic zone strapi

Tags: strapi

, please help with this issue. I'm trying to output the added dynamic zones from stpapi to next, but I can't find how to correctly form a request in postman so that I can register it in next

add dynamic zones

[image: 1]

generated a request in postman

/?populate=*

[image: 2]

http://localhost:1337/api/courses/8/?populate=*

I see that my dynamic zone is displayed in the collection, but what query do I need to generate to get the populate dymanic zone?

I added dimachin zones as shown in the guide

Answer (score 0):

This section of the documentation gives you some examples of querying dynamic zones using REST: https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/api/rest/populate-select#deeply-populate-a-dynamic-zone-with-2-components

In your case, it might be: `http://localhost:1337/api/courses/8/?populate[sheldued][populate]=*`